# Android -- Map markers displaying differently (dip/px or decompression)

Tags: android

I'm having an odd problem with my map pin sizes.  To preserve dynamic-ness, the map pins for different categories are stored on a site's server so that they can be changed at any point even after the app is published.

I'm caching the pins every time I download them and I only ever re-download them if the server sends back a bit saying that one has changed since last I downloaded it.  The first time I grab the pins, I use the bitmaps before I save them to files and the map markers are the correct size.  Every time after that I'm loading a saved version of the pins straight from the image file.  These are displaying considerably **smaller** than they are when using the bitmaps from the first download.

At first, I thought it was a problem with the way I'm saving the PNGs, but their sizes are correct (64 x 64).  Is this a dip/px issue or do I need to decompress the image files with some sort of option?

Here's how I grab the images the first time:

```
public static Bitmap loadMapPin(String category, int width, int height) {
        URL imageUrl;
        category = category.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
        try {
            imageUrl = new URL(PIN_URL+category+".png");
            InputStream is = (InputStream) imageUrl.getContent();
            Options options = new Options();

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; //Only find the dimensions

            //Decode without downloading to find dimensions
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

            boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - height) >= Math.abs(options.outWidth - width);
            if(options.outHeight * options.outWidth >= width * height){
                // Load, scaling to smallest power of 2 that'll get it <= desired dimensions
               double sampleSize = scaleByHeight
                     ? options.outHeight / height
                     : options.outWidth / width;
               options.inSampleSize = 
                     (int)Math.pow(2d, Math.floor(
                     Math.log(sampleSize)/Math.log(2d)));
            }
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false; //Download image this time

            is.close();
            is = (InputStream) imageUrl.getContent();
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
            return img;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here's how I'm loading them from the cached file:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that, by default, decompressing an image to a bitmap doesn't scale with high density screens.  You have to set the density to none.  In other words, you specify that the image is meant for an unknown density.

Solution:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
b.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
```